# How can I use regex to match the contents by using expect?

Tags: linux, expect

I am new to expect for using the regular expression. trying to parse below input stream. How it can be parse with regexp. As CNTXID is incremental.

```
"Data"
                  CNTXID = 1
                      AP = 99
                     DEF = FALSE
               
                  CNTXID = 2
                      AP = 88
                     DEF = TRUE
               
                  CNTXID = 3
                      AP = 77
                     DEF = FALSE
```

and CNTXID is not fix.

Required Output

```
CNTXID_1 = 1
    AP_1 = 99
   DEF_1 = FALSE

CNTXID_2 = 2
    AP_2 = 88
   DEF_2 = TRUE

CNTXID_3 = 3
    AP_3 = 77
   DEF_3 = FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

`expect` is not supposed to be used for modifying data. It is designed for "got a message - send response". What you describing is just a data reformatting.

It can be done easy with Perl:

```
#!/bin/perl
my $n=0;
while(<>) {
    if (/CNTXID = (\d+)/) {
        $n = $1;
    }
    if (/(\S+) = (\S+)/) {
        printf "%7s_%d = %s\n", $1, $n, $2;
    } elsif (/$\s*^/) {
        print "\n";
    }
}
```